# How to split pip install into steps in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
    zlib-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    geoip-dev

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If there are any problems with downloading or installing the dependencies in `requirements.txt` when I start the build again `pip install` downloads everything again.

What are the best practices for Dockerfile in this case? Is it necessary to split requirements? Use separate volumes? Or is there an instruction other then `RUN` that is dedicated just for such cases?

Comment: well if I understand correctly thats the whole idea of using docker. whenever you build image from scratch you create a whole new image by using dockerfile. I am running a python project right now what I do is I run pip install inside container then if library is ok to install to docker image then I put inside requirement file then I build my image again

Answer (score 1):

Every instruction you add in the Dockerfile on build adds a new layer to the build. For each instruction run on build the image layer caches the contents of that layer on top of the other ones. Layers can be cached between builds if the results are expected to be the same every time.

In your case, if the step where it's building the requirements file fails, that step will not be considered complete, meaning the next time you run your build it'll start that step over (which will run the installation for everything in `requirements.txt`).

One thing you can do to shorten rebuilds is to introduce a multi-stage build where the first stage installs requirements and the second stage runs your application; this way the only time the first stage of requirements is run is when you change your `requirements.txt`.

```
# FROM x as y
# will name this stage of the build as "dependencies"
FROM python:3.6-alpine as dependencies

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
    zlib-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    geoip-dev

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# This is the next stage of the build building off your dependencies
FROM dependencies as application

RUN my_application.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in the process of troubleshooting a Dockerfile build. The layer will not be applied to the image if it throws an error while building, so it will have to rebuild it again from the beginning - that is just how Docker works.

If you're looking to shorten the feedback loop while troubleshooting your build, you could split up the pip installs into multiple files, or even exec into the container and manually pip install the requirements, but once you have it working I would put all the pip installs into one command to keep the Dockerfile optimized.

Comment: Not only debugging, sometimes package is failed to download because of network error. Or say, on development stage I try different packages, I want to add a new dependency in requirements and don't want it speed up the build time